# Excel help on Data visualization of a simple data

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I need a help in visualizing the below data in excel. The data should be proportioned to 100 with the total. I need a stacked bar lines side by side for each month(always 4 months). The colour green should correspond to 'perfect', yellow to 'needs recheck' and red to 'spoiled'. In the y axis the data should be marked till 100 in intervals. Please help me in visualizing this with excel.

Note that the height of all the bar lines will be the same as we are proportioning to 100.

my data

[image: data]

my desired output

[image: output]

Comment: Use stacked column chart

Comment: How can I proportion the total to 100.?

Comment: Use % of total for each value stacked in separate columns is the simple way.  X axis however is not easy, so concatenate Cells for state & month (suggest using number) into one cell for X axis

Comment: e.g.  G2=A2&” “ & B2. Then rotate X axis text -90 deg then insert rows between states.. suggest using abbreviated states NY, FL and the convert month to number so X axis shows NY 9 10 11 12  FL 9 10 11 12 since the columns are too narrow.. More complex Vbasic is needed to do what you want

Comment: However I think a stacked line graph with blank rows between states would be better without colors. Excel might be primitive about merged X axis titles With multiple rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the range to a table with Ctrl+T, then select the Place, Month, Perfect, Needs recheck and Spoiled columns, then use Insert>Charts>2D Column>100% Stacked Column:

[image]

To edit each series to the desired colors, right-click on that color and change the Fill color to whatever you want it to be. To change the series names, right-click the chart and select "Select Data", then use Edit on each series and change the Series name to your preferred value.

Inspired by Reddy, TIL you can delete some of the values in the Place column to cause the x-axis category headers to merge (you can leave the data formatted as a Table):

[image]

Comment: If you dont convert it to a table, but merge places, your x-axis labels will look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9POj.png)

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks. Generally I try to avoid merging cells wherever possible as it causes issues with other operations.

Comment: Your rule of avoid merging is certainly correct and wise.

Comment: Great answer I swear against using merged cells, but this is the first real good use I have seen for them

Comment: merging cells was good for this. Thanks @ReddyLutonadio